# My current MySQL join is not working

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following tables:

Users

```
id | name
-----------------
 1 | Johny Bravo
```

Orders

```
id | users_id | number
----------------------
 1 |    1    | 111111
 2 |    1    | 222222
 3 |    1    | 333333
 4 |    1    | 444444
```

Example

```
id | text | number
------------------
 1 | test | 111111
 2 | test | 111111
 3 | test | 222222
 4 | test | 222222
 5 | test | 333333
 6 | test | 333333
```

Desired Outcome

```
id: 1
name: Johny Brawo
count(orders): 4
count(example): 6
```

My current query, which doesn't work

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, count(orders.id), count(example.id)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.users_id=users.id
LEFT JOIN example ON example.number=orders.number
GROUP BY users.id
```

My current result

```
id: 1
name: Johny Brawo
count(orders): 8
count(example): 8
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you receive instead of just 'not work'?

Comment: update question

Comment: I can be considered bad etiquette to write a question title in all caps.

Comment: @ArkadiuszG. You know, you REALLY should accept an answer, if it works for you. Not doing that is quite bad manners here.

Answer (score 3):

try `count(distinct orders.id), count(distinct example.id)`

I've not done any MySQL really, but this works in other Databases...

Comment: Thanks, is ok! But I can order after count(distinct orders.id)? :)

Comment: You can definitely order by any column. MySQL is not very strict when it comes to grouping, so you will be able to ORDER BY any field in `users` table, as well as `COUNT` columns. See my answer for an explanation, what exactly your query does.

Answer (score 1):

Starting - a little bit of theory. What does your query do?

First it `SELECT`s something from `users` table.

Then it `LEFT JOIN`s with `orders` table. Number of returned rows is a multiplication of rows from `users` table and matching rows from `orders` table. So with only this join you will have 6 rows, each one with `Johny Bravo` as user, but with different `orders` data.

Then - another `LEFT JOIN`. This time with `example` table. Again - a number of returned rows is a multiplication of rows from `orders` table and matching rows from `example` table. So without `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` you will have eight rows of result.

Now, the `GROUP BY` query part. What does it do? It just groups rows with matching `GROUP BY` column(s). So it will group all rows with same `users.id`. There are eight of them.

Standard `COUNT()` will return a number of rows with not null value. As there were eight rows, both counts will return 8.

Now, as @GPW suggested, the solution is a `COUNT(DISTINCT x)`. This function returns a count of **unique** not null rows.

Thus, the query should look like:

```sql
SELECT users.id, users.name, count(DISTINCT orders.id), count(DISTINCT example.id)
FROM users
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.users_id=users.id
LEFT JOIN example ON example.number=orders.number
GROUP BY users.id
```

**UPDATE - ordering and strict databases**

You have also asked about ordering the result. You can order it by any column from your query. As MySQL is not very strict when it comes to grouping, you will also be able to order by any column from `users` table, as `users` table results are unique (grouped by id). You can also add, for example `ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT orders.id) DESC` to find users with largest number of orders.

Most databases, though, is more strict in `GROUP BY` queries. It allows to `SELECT` only columns with aggregated values or those explicitly contained in `GROUP BY` clause. So your `GROUP BY` clause should rather look like

```sql
GROUP BY users.id, users.name
```